# I want to combine GET & PUT call in single script using PHP or Python, currently I am using Postman

Tags: api, get, postman, prestashop, put

This is my GET API call in POSTMAN

```
 {
        "stock_available": {
            "id": 271,
            "id_product": "231",
            "id_product_attribute": "0",
            "id_shop": "1",
            "id_shop_group": "0",
            "quantity": "0",
            "depends_on_stock": "0",
            "out_of_stock": "0",
            "location": ""
        }
    }
```

This is where I am converting response into variable

```
const response = pm.response.json();
pm.globals.set("quantity", response.stock_available.quantity);
```

This is PUT call I want to make

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <stock_available>
              <id>1445</id>
            <id_product>1406</id_product>
        <id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute>
        <id_shop>1</id_shop>
        <id_shop_group>0</id_shop_group>
        <quantity>{{quantity}}</quantity>
        <depends_on_stock>0</depends_on_stock>
        <out_of_stock>2</out_of_stock>
        <location></location>
    </stock_available>
    </prestashop>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<?php
define('DEBUG', false);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', '*your url here*');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '*your api key here*');

try {

    $webService= new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);



    $xml = $webService->get([
        'resource' => 'stock_availables',
        'id' => 231,
    ]);
    $quantity = $xml->stock_available->quantity;
    
    $xml = $webService->get([
        'resource' => 'stock_availables',
        'id' => 1406,
    ]);
    $xml->stock_available->quantity = $quantity;
    $opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $opt['id'] = 1406;
    $opt['resource'] = 'stock_availables';
    $xml = $webService->edit($opt);
}catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    echo "Error:<br>";
    echo  $ex->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
```